# Is it possible to append part of table to the botton of same table in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table that is structured like this:

```
Year | Month | Item 1 | Type 1 | Value 1 | Cost 1 | Item 2 | Type 2 | Value 2 | Cost 2 | 
2020 |  Aug  |    A   |   AX   | Value A | Cost A |    B   |   BY   | Value B | Cost B | 
...  |  ...  |   ...  |   ...  |   ...   |   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |   ...   |   ...  |
```

I wanted to change this table so that it looks like:

```
Year | Month | Item  | Type  | Value   | Cost
2020 |  Aug  |   A   |   AX  | Value A | Cost A
2020 |  Aug  |   B   |   BY  | Value B | Cost B
etc...
```

Since it has a lot of rows and I have multiple tables like this, I wanted to do it inside Power Query, but I not managed that yet. So I'm asking if anyone here knows if its possible or how to do it.

I tried unpivoting the columns after Year and Month, and then pivoting them later, but I end up with a lot of null values.

**This is what I have managed to do:**

[image]

Thanks for the help, and sorry for the rough English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming source data is in **Table1**, with columns and column header names as specified (**Year, Month, ...**)

Basically ...

Unpivot

Add index

Use math on the index to count by 4's (the number of repeating columns)

Group on the Month and Year, and the new modified index

Expand

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
UnpivotIt = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Year", "Month"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
RemoveAttribute = Table.RemoveColumns(UnpivotIt,{"Attribute"}),
AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(RemoveAttribute, "Index", 0, 1),
// we have 4 columns of repeating data, so use 4 in row below
Divide = Table.TransformColumns(AddIndex, {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 4), Int64.Type}}),
Grouping = Table.Group(Divide,{"Index", "Year","Month"}, {{"Values", each Record.FromList([Value],{"Item","Type","Value","Cost"}), type record}}),
RemoveIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(Grouping,{"Index"}),
#"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(RemoveIndex , "Values", {"Item", "Type", "Value", "Cost"}, {"Item", "Type", "Value", "Cost"})
in #"Expanded Values"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But could you explain me the "Grouping" part a bit further? I coudn't understand what the "Record.FromList" command does in this case.

Comment: Sorry, no idea, just picked it up along the way .. converts to Record rather than the normal table when you group. This is pretty much the only step requiring manual code edit